# Why $\sigma^{-2}_i \ \vec{u}_i^T U \Sigma^2 U^T \vec{u}_i = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra

Why $$\sigma^{-2}_i \vec{u}_i^T A A^T \vec{u}_i =
\sigma^{-2}_i \vec{u}_i^T U \Sigma U^T U \Sigma U^T \vec{u}_i = 
 \sigma^{-2}_i \ \vec{u}_i^T U \Sigma^2 U^T \vec{u}_i = 1$$

I do not understand the last step, how we get from $\sigma^{-2}_i \ \vec{u}_i^T U \Sigma^2 U^T \vec{u}_i$ to 1.

Where $\sigma$ is i-th singular value and $\vec{u_i}$ is i-th row of U from singular value decomposition.

A is PSD.

Could anyone walk me to the solution of 1 in details?

Appreciate.

Comment: Hint: The singular vectors of a positive semi definite matrix are orthonormal. With this what should be $U^T u_i$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u_i$ is an eigenvector of $A$, and $\sigma_i$ is its corresponding eigenvalue, then $A u_i = \sigma_i u_i$. Thus, $u^T_i A^T = \sigma_i u^T_i$. Since A is PSD, $A = A^T$ and therefore $u^T_i A = \sigma_i u^T_i$.
Now, replacing in $\sigma^{-2}_i u^T_i A A^T u_i = 
\sigma^{-2}_i (u^T_i A) (A u_i) = \sigma^{-2}_i (\sigma_i u^T_i)(\sigma_i u_i) = u^T_i u_i $. Since all $u_i$ have unit norm, $u^T_i u_i = 1$

Comment: I am a bit unclear why $Au_i = \sigma_i u_i $. Could you elaborate?

Comment: By definition, you will find it in the first lines: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors